# XDebug breakpoints aren't hitting

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to get XDebug (version 2.5.4) working with PHP Storm, with PHP 7.

I am using Windows and running my application off of a CentOS virtual machine, with PHP 7 set up in the CLI settings of PHP Storm, in order to debug.

Here is what my configuration looks like:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=etc... 
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

I am using Postman, with **?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM** at the end of the API endpoint, and the cookie with contents **XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM;** in the body.

I am clearly setting breakpoints, but I keep getting the message **Debug session was finished without being paused**

I also have the path mapping set up correctly, between the File/Directory and Absolute path on the server:

I can also get it to stop at the first line by setting the "Break at first line in PHP scripts" checkbox in PHP Storm.  I just doesn't stop at my set break points.

Can anyone recommend what I need to do in order to get the break points to hit?

Comment: and what does the (not configured-in) xdebug log tell you ?

Comment: have you tried the 'stop at first line of code' option? If PHPStorm recognizes an incoming debug session but does not stop that's usually because of wrong (or missing) file mappings.

Comment: Hi masterfloda, I should have mentioned that in the original post, yes it works on stopping at the first line.

Comment: YvesLeBorg, how do I access the not configured-in log?

Comment: you have a syntax error, you're missing the closing `"` after `xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM`

Comment: Hi Derek, I noticed that and corrected it, and am it's still not hitting the points.

Comment: I also very carefully checked the path to the file on the server, in the mapping.